# live PHP webapp deployment

Tags: webserver, deployment, rolling-release

I am looking to setup Bamboo to do live PHP deployments (same principles can apply to Jenkins)

I would like to be able to do live releases with the push of a button in the Bamboo application.

However, I would like to ensure that sessions remain active.  I.e. the web user does not experience any downtime.  If there was a problem then it tries its best to be resilient.

Any recommendations for a high-level concept for how to achieve this?

My thoughts are it could work something like the following

two web servers running

```
webapp-live -- port 80 public 
webapp-deploy -- port 81 private
```

Strategy

```
1) Push project files onto server
2) /var/www/releases/web-app-tag-number.zip
3) unzip file
4) deploy to webapp-deploy
5) sanity checks i.e. webapp-deploy loads homepage ok
6) swap deploy with live - use symlink to re-point files?  (will this keep sessions alive?)
```

I'm sure this kind of thing has been done several times.

Wondered if there was a better strategy?

Comment: All it depends on is where your session files are stored and whether your PHP configuration allows symbolic links to be followed.

Comment: I'm unsure as to what type of web server you're using that can not handle vhosts and requires different ports though.  The rest of your concept seems fairly straight-forward.

Comment: Why do you open a bounty when you don't even provide the clarifications requested?  Do you really need to use 2 separate ports for it to work?  I think you're actually over-thinking something that can be done in less than an hour.

Comment: Julie fair points.  I dont have a strict requirements for extra ports..  That was my initial thoughts on how to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

`1 public facing load balancer (e.g. HAproxy)`

`Two backend webservers.`

1. Remove one webserver from the pool (with Haproxy this is done via admin socket. See [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/249316/how-can-i-remove-balanced-node-from-haproxy-via-command-line))
2. Wait for the sessions to end on that server.
3. Push, unzip, deploy project files to disabled server.
4. Test without going through loadbalancer. (i.e. localhost)
5. Re-enable server.
6. Repeat from step 1 with the second server.

"Disabling" the server puts the server into maintenance mode, after waiting for all current connections to expire. Of course a connection is not necessarily equal to a "session". So, depending on how you handle sessions, there may need to be some session replication between the two servers or a separate session DB (a new [SPOF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_point_of_failure)) that both servers rely on.

This way your users won't experience any downtime. Plus you get the added benefit of some load balancing.

Sadly, setting up HAproxy this way can be a pain.